# Cannot install Firefox in Semplice Linux

Tags: apt, firefox, ppa

I am using [Semplice Linux](http://semplice-linux.org/) in VMware on Windows 7. It works fine but I cannot install Firefox.

Semplice Linux is based on Debian Sid (unstable branch) with an Openbox desktop.

This is what I get

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 daily (or even multiple builds per day) for various mozilla projects and branches.

For questions and bugs with software in this archive, please contact <email address hidden> or visit #ubuntu-mozillateam on freenode.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 167, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 595, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Semplice/heaven
```

---

**EDIT**:

After adding the sources as indicated in the answer I get this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/unstable/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/unstable/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
c@c-semplice:~$ sudo apt-get install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package firefox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Why you need to add a PPA to install Firefox?

Comment: @Braiam - you mean just download and run ("portable") - as indicated in my workaround answer? I though that adding the PPA when it is not there already like in Ubuntu etc is the proper way to do it...

Comment: No, I mean why not just install iceweasel, which is the name of Firefox for Debian? And no, that's the wrong way. You shouldn't install Ubuntu packages on non-Ubuntu systems.

Comment: @Braiam - well, I prefer to have Firefox too, although I have nothing against Iceweasel. What shouldn't I use an opensource crossplatform browser that I always used in Linux, Windows and Mac? But I always used Ubuntu based linuxes and what I know about Linux is limited to Ubuntu is a sense (and Ubuntu is based on Debian, I thought, so things should not be that different etc). I was not able to try non-Ubuntu Linuxes on my laptops but in a virtual machine I want to. -- To reformulate my question: **what is the proper way to install Firefox in Debian?**

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel "Iceweasel is a fork [from Firefox] .... Beyond that, they will be basically identical. (quoting Roberto C. Sanchez post in debian-devel mailing list)" just install iceweasel. Is Firefox, just with another name.

Comment: @Braiam - should I understand that *in Debian the proper way to install Firefox is to install Iceweasel*? -

Comment: "Proper"? What you mean with proper? If I want a Firefox-like browser in Debian I install Iceweasel. Proper or not, it is easier and guaranteed to work. I do not know anything about "proper".

Comment: Sorry for my vague language. I mean *the common way of getting Firefox in the Debian community*. My question is **about** Firefox and I want an answer on that. I **do** use Iceweasel, and other Mozilla based browsers like Seamonkey (now even [PaleMoon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pm4linux/), based on FF, but that does not follow the latest design changes in FF, is available for Linux. More on this larger issue, my older question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/228309/47206)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary an limited solution to use Firefox without proper installation:

--following [this](https://superuser.com/a/322379/162573) answer --

- Downloaded the [Firefox package](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
- Unpacked it. Now Firefox can be launched from there.
- Creating a `Firefox.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` would add that to the menu entries.

Answer (score 1):

The ppa does not "know" about Semplice. If it's similar enough to Debian sid, try adding the ppa manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu unstable main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu unstable main
```

Comment: still does not work. does that mean that  the condition "*similar enough to Debian sid*" is not fulfilled?

Comment: You're now getting 404 errors, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Comment: but would that help me install Firefox?

Comment: **What is the proper way to install Firefox in a such Debian-based Linux?** -- On getting 404 errors and the link in your comment: that solution is on how to **remove** such sources, while your answer tells me how to add them, which I did. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please open another question.